# Read and write dat file in php

Tags: php, file, file-io, io

recently i've used Maxmind geoip to locate country & city based on the ip. It has huge content inside the dat files. but retrieving of those records happens within a seconds.  so i'm so curious to learn and use the technology in php.

First i've seen some video files are using this .dat extension files and now text information. so what is .dat extension actually? is it possible to read and write in php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what I know, *dat* extension means a generic file in which you could write what you need, in the format you please.
I mean, in every file you could do that, but generally if you find an *xml file* you assume that inside you find xml formatted text; on the contrary *dat* files are not recognized as something you can decode with a specific software if you don't know who and how wrote it.

Comment: Yes Marco, it isn't a standard format. But what i noticed is, they've a huge list of city,country database inside the dat file and it's been retrieved within a second. that is why i'm interested to use it. I think you are trying mean, we don't know what method they used to create that dat file. is it so?

Comment: The method used to create it does not matter. The format in which data is stored does.

Comment: @Sekar: I mean that to parse a file you **must** know how data inside is organized. Then we could _study" if cities are alphabetically sorted and if data is well structured to be retrieved quickly. This could make a great difference in time.

Comment: @Marco: they should've well structured, that's why retrieval is so quick. will they answer it, if we raise any support tickets? ;)

Comment: @Sekar: I don't know if they like you could read their file with another software that's not the one developed from them... Anyway, give them a chance: ask them and wait for their answer. Can you post a little bunch of that file? Is it ascii or binary? Please: post it editing your question, not in a comment!

Comment: @Macro: i tried to open, but text editor or other document viewers aren't recognizing it. but they used php to read the file, like how we use to read a text file.we've to try and construct the structure using how they read the file. But due to its a paid one i cannot post the method they used as it may raise issues in future.

Comment: @Sekar: sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do. PHP is just one of the dozens languages you can use to parse that _dat file_; to open and parse it you **must** know file structure (i.e. how data is organized): without it give up, you can do nothing. So stop worrying about PHP and study (use Notepad++) what is inside that file.

Comment: @Sekar: you're telling me that this file is part of a licensed software: be careful that probably you **cannot** use data inside _dat file_!

Comment: @Marco: I think you didn't get me. What i said is,they've used php to read that file. for example,if there is query like "select id,name from profile" means, we can assume that there is two columns id,name in profile table. Same way we try to know how they organized their data by using their parsing methodology itself. moreover i got the license to use it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3200/discussion-between-marco-and-sekar)

Answer (score 0):

The files will most likely be in a custom format that they developed; if it's open source you could reimplement it in PHP (if it isn't already written in PHP), or maybe access the data through an API.

The speed will come from the fact that it'll be indexed in some way, or it's like "for every record move 100 bytes further into the file".

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of questions here.

First, the file is a [database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) - it stores data. There are lots of database models - relational, herarchical, object-oriented, vector, hypercube, keystore....there are implementations of all these available off the shelf.

Some databases are more apposite to managing particular data structures than others. Geospatial data is a common specialization - so much so that a lot of other database types will provide vector functionality (e.g. mysql and postgresql which are relational databases).

For most database systems, the application using the services of the database does not access the data file directly - instead access is mediated via another process - this is particularly relevant for PHP since it typically runs as multiple independent processes with no sophisticated file locking functionality.

So if you were looking to implement IP to geography info yourself, I'd recommend sticking to a relational database or a nosql keystore (you don't need the geospatial stuff for forward lookups).

But do bear in mind that IP to geo lookup data is not nearly as accurate/precise as the peolpe selling the products would have you believe. If your objective is to get accurate position information about your users, the HTML5 [geolocation API](http://html5demos.com/geo) provides much better data - the problem is availability of the functionality on user's browsers.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. but my question is on reading and writing .dat files using php. to explain why i'm interested on the technology i used maxminds geolocator as an example. i knew that city information are only 80% accurate, but i tried to mean having those huge datas they're able to retrieve in a second for any given ip.

Comment: @Sekar: You're missing the point. Yes, to quite a large extent the data structure affects performance - but there are already very efficient implementations of data access layers using different data models available where *you can see the code and datastructures for yourself*. GeoIP lookup is **NOT** a huge dataset (approx 20 million addresses - the reason why this is not 4.3 billion should be obvious - but even that is not a huge dataset). If my queries took a second to complete (on much larger datasets) I'd be very concerned about the performance.

Comment: yeah! that was a valid point, the dat files comes around around 20 mb only. May be that is the reason for the performance.Thanks.